# How to fail jenkins job if warnings count is growing

Tags: jenkins, warnings, jenkins-plugins

There is a known number of build warnings in the compilation and I would like Jenkins to fail the build if the warnings count is growing beyond this number.
Is there any plugin that can do such thing?

Comment: The warnings plugin allows various settings regarding thresholds and more.

Comment: @DominikGebhart I can't find this option.

Comment: Just saw this is a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944257/how-to-mark-build-as-unstable-when-warning-trend-has-arisen

Comment: Check the [plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin), you need to add a post-build step *Scan for compiler warnings* to get to configure the behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mark build as unstable when warning trend has arisen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944257/how-to-mark-build-as-unstable-when-warning-trend-has-arisen)