# How to catch only new warning in jenkins using warning plugin

Tags: jenkins, warnings, jenkins-plugins

Warning plugin in jenkin gives all warning present in the code base but I want only new warning. Can any one tell the configuration or any method to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mark build as unstable when warning trend has arisen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944257/how-to-mark-build-as-unstable-when-warning-trend-has-arisen)